# Using 'eval' special form in ClojureScript to determine if a form is literal

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I'm writing a function which **determines if a form** (e.g `(reverse [1 2 3])`) **is literal**. To do this I have the following code:

```
(defn literal? [form]
(let [evaluation (try
                     (eval form)
                     (catch Exception exception false))]
    (if evaluation
      (= evaluation form)
      true)))
```

This tries to evaluate the form first; if that fails then we consider the form as literal.

If the form evaluates successfully then we check further if the evaluation is equal to the form itself. If so it is literal.

The function works when applied to `[1 2 3]` in a .clj file, but in a .cljs file I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at eval (/home/peter/ide/src-cljs/ide/core.cljs[eval16]:71:14)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.<anonymous> (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:35236:461)
    at b (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:6188:14)
    at a (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:6234:18)
    at cljs.core.do_dispatch (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:13583:26)
    at cljs.core.MultiFn.cljs$core$IMultiFn$_dispatch$arity$2 (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:13655:32)
    at cljs.core._dispatch (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:13568:14)
    at a (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:13662:32)
    at b [as call] (file:///opt/lighttable-0.8.1-linux/resources/app/core/node_modules/lighttable/bootstrap.js:13666:14)
```

Does anyone have a solution which will work in ClojureScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but it's a little tricky!

If you go to clojurescript.io and enter this mysterious incantation:

```
(js/cljs.js.eval (js/cljs.js.empty-state) [1 2 3] (fn [x] (prn "********" x)))
```

Then check your developer console, you will see:

```
"********" {:value [1 2 3]}
```

Along with other output that occurs.

Hopefully this convinces you that (a) eval works! (b) eval is a little more complicated in cljs.

Why all the js interop you may ask? Well in the context of the REPL that is executing, those symbols aren't in the current state of the compiler, as the javascript was created when the site was compiled. There are ways to preload the state, but require some work to achieve. Don't worry, none of that is relevant if you are calling `eval` as part of your program (instead of from the REPL). If you are using eval in your program you can write code like this:

```
(ns ....... (:require .....
  [cljs.js :refer [eval empty-state js-eval]]))


(eval (empty-state)
        [1 2 3]
        {:eval       js-eval
         :source-map true
         :context    :expr}
        (fn [x] (prn "*****" x)))
```

And it produces the same effect:

```
"*****" {:value [1 2 3]}
```

In short, you need to refer `eval` from `cljs.js`, and it requires some state to be passed along.

Here are some references, because... it's confusing, and these give great details:

1. http://clojurescript.io/ Check out the code for building this site.
2. Read Mike Fikes blog! https://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2016-01-22-clojurescript-eval.html (and other posts) He wrote most of the bootstrapping code and uses it actively in Planck.
3. https://yogthos.net/posts/2015-11-12-ClojureScript-Eval.html
4. http://ctford.github.io/klangmeister/ Great reference for preloading state.

Comment: Thanks for the detail; I get a 'goog.require could not find: cljs.js' when I try to require cljs.js in my namespace. Is there a dependency I need to add to my project.clj? Apologies if this should be obvious!

Comment: Most likely problem there is the version of ClojureScript, cljs.js was only added recently. For reference I tried it with 1.8.51 (but there are even newer versions now). Please let me know if using a newer version resolves it for you.

Comment: I updated my Clojure, ClojureScript and lein versions to 1.8.0, 1.9.89 and 1.1.3 respectively, and after fixing some other breakages everything appears to be working; cheers!

Comment: Did you mean to link to this blog entry from Mike Fikes? https://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2016-01-22-clojurescript-eval.html

Comment: Nice, that does seem more relevant; I've edited to include.